# Change text selection icon or color on API <21

Tags: android, android-styles

This is android 4.1 (api 16) When you long click an action-bar appears with the options. Is there a way to change those 2 icons, or at least their color?

- changing `colorAccent` won't work
- changing `colorControlActivated` won't work
- using [holo-colors](http://android-holo-colors.com/) won't work

[image]

app style is `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

Comment: Have you tried colorControlActivated?

Comment: yes, won't work

Comment: It looks like you are using an old Holo theme though (creating a new project and adding an EditText by default uses the colorAccent as the selector) , perhaps paste your styles and your usage of EditText in the question so we can help more.